# How to pass data in body of a HttpConnection in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Actually I want to pass data in body of a httpconnection.

Using apache httpclient library in blackberry, integrated jar file in my project but getting compilation error while running my project.

Kindly updated me on the same.

Comment: Which errors do you get?

Comment: Apache HttpClient library is incompatible with the way networking is handled on BB. I.e. you can not use it.

Answer (score 3):

I have not tried using Apache HttpClient lib in a BB project before, because I did not for a moment think it would work...
In short, you need the code to be compatible with J2ME, and compilable using the RIM tool chain. And then we get into other problems....

First of, be aware that networking in BlackBerry is NOT as straightforward as one might wish.
Have a look at this video for the back ground theory: [Networking Transports on the BB Platform](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Networking-Transports-II/ta-p/446742?name=NetworkingTransportsII)

Ok, then for some code (I assume here you already went through the trouble of obtaining an HttpConnection):

```
byte [] bodyBytes = getBodyBytesFromSomewhere();
OutputStream out = httpConnection.openOutputStream();
out.write(bodyBytes);
out.flush();
out.close();//If you are done, which I'm guessing you are
```

The above code is of course very simplistic, and completely ignores all the many, many errors that will occur during network IO.

I would suggest you also look at [this API](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/package-summary.html),[this forum entry](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21128/Network_API_Overview_1251781_11.jsp),[and this one](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/21128/Network_communication_overview_1226079_11.jsp). OS6.0 also introduced a new HTTP Connection API - can't find a link for that right now (sorry!)

Comment: Are you referring to the [ConnectionFactory class](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/io/transport/ConnectionFactory.html)?  That was introduced in 5.0, but is very useful indeed.

Comment: No, it is the API available under "net.rim.device.api.io.messaging" - I had a link to a nice blackberry knowledge article about it, but now I can't find it. I believe RIM called it the "Communications API"

Comment: Ahh, this [Communication API](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/communication_api_1984365_11.html).  Link is for 7.1, but was introduced in 6.0, as you said.